# Is it safe to return a stream?

Tags: c#, stream, httpwebresponse

I have an wrapper class that has a method that goes off and downloads a file from a web server and needs to return said file. The HttpWebResponse object returns a Stream for the body.

Should I return a stream? Or should I convert it to a byte array and return that instead?

This wrapper class may be used in several places so I need a solid way to return the file. In every case, the file will be saved somewhere after receiving it from the adapter class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, it's fine.

Long answer: Yes, it's completely safe to return a `Stream`. The garbage collector is smart in .NET and you don't have to worry about the `Stream` being disposed of or anything. (That is, unless you call `Dispose()` on it — which you should not if you are planning on reusing it.)

Comment: Ta very much. Just wanted some reassurance as I don't deal in streams very often and wasn't sure I was making some huger faux pas.

Answer (score 3):

Returning `Stream` object is totally valid. It would be responsibility of the code that calls the method returning stream to dispose it. Question is: does disposing response object in your wrapper method also dispose the stream? If so, then copy its content into a `MemoryStream` or make a temp file and return open stream to it instead.